# DRYing up factory_girl test setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have the following test setup which I'm now finding necessary to use in multiple test suites.

```
  before do
    @guest, @host = FactoryGirl.create(:user), FactoryGirl.create(:user)

    @booking = FactoryGirl.create(
      :booking,
      user: @guest,
      listing: FactoryGirl.create(:listing, user: @host),
      state: "unaccepted_by_guest_or_host"
    )   
  end
```

It's obviously not ideal to have this same exact code in multiple files. What I think I would prefer is something more like this if possible:

```
  before do
    @guest, @host = FactoryGirl.create(:user), FactoryGirl.create(:user)

    @booking = FactoryGirl.create(
      :complete_booking,
      guest: @guest,
      host: @host,
    )   
  end
```

That would of course still be a little duplication, but I wouldn't feel nearly as bad about that.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to achieve? Is something even better possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always define a test helper that given a `@guest` and a `@host`, it sets up the thing as you listed it in your first snippet. Same benefits, none of the duplication.